# Create cv::Mat from IDirect3DSurface9

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, directx, mat

The app I'm working on, currently takes a screenshot of DirectX-based game.
Using `IDirect3DDevice9::GetBackBuffer` results in **`IDirect3DDevice9`** object.

Now I'm looking for a way to get the raw image directly, because I need to process it in OpenCV later.

The only example I found was in [OpenCV directx samples](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/directx/d3d9ex_interop.cpp), so I try to initialize `cv::Mat` the following way:

```
IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface = nullptr;
auto cops = pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SCRATCH, &pSurface, NULL);
auto gfbd = pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pSurface);

D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
ZeroMemory(&lockedRect, sizeof(D3DLOCKED_RECT));
pSurface->LockRect(&lockedRect, 0, D3DLOCK_READONLY);

//**** OpenCV

cv::Mat D3DSurface(ScreenHeight, ScreenWidth, CV_8UC4, lockedRect.pBits, lockedRect.Pitch);

cv::imshow("D3DSurface", D3DSurface);
```

Unfortunately, it throws the following exception: **d:\lib\opencv\build\install\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp:410: error: (-215) total() == 0 || data != NULL in function cv::Mat::Mat**

---

I'm aware I can probably do it by saving `IDirect3DSurface9` to a file a then read it with `cv::imread`, but I'd rather avoid unnecessary disk operations unless there's no other way.

**And btw saving `IDirect3DSurface9` to a file works fine, I checked it using:**

```
D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile(L"D:\\ss1.bmp", D3DXIFF_BMP, pSurface, NULL, NULL);
```

---

### Edit:

As *@Asesh* mentioned, I tried to use `D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileInMemory`, now the code is like:

```
LPD3DXBUFFER buffer;
D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileInMemory(&buffer, D3DXIFF_BMP, pSurface, NULL, NULL);
DWORD imSize = buffer->GetBufferSize();
void* imgBuffer = buffer->GetBufferPointer();

//**** OpenCV

cv::Mat D3DSurface(ScreenHeight, ScreenWidth, CV_8UC4, imgBuffer);
cv::imshow("D3DSurface", D3DSurface);
```

**The `cv::Mat` is created successfully, but it gets distorted.** Reversing the image should not be a problem, however I don't know what is wrong with the colors:

[image]

Using `CV_8UC3` type in `cv::Mat` constructor instead results in:

[image]

Here is how the original screenshot should look like: (result of `D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile`)

[image]

Comment: You can use D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileInMemory to save surface in memory

Comment: @Asesh thanks :) I was able to create `cv::Mat` successfully, but there's problem with the image now. I made and edit above.

Comment: Looks like it's back buffer rather than front buffer. Did you use the same pointer to IDirect3DSurface9? If yes then can you check the result of both D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileInMemory and D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile?

Comment: In other words, just write the contents of  D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileInMemory to a file and compare the result with the output of D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile.

Comment: What is the format of your pSurface? You can get it with GetDesc and examine the Format field of the D3DSURFACE_DESC structure. If it is not d3dformat_x8r8g8b8 then you can't use CV_8UC4/CV_8UC3 directly.

Comment: You can also check this: https://github.com/Balaje/opencv-1/blob/master/samples/directx/d3d9ex_interop.cpp. If your backbuffer format is YUV, you might need to CreateOffscreenPlainSurface with D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8 first, copy the backbuffer to it using StretchRect. And then create the CV_8UC4 cv::Mat from the offscreen D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8 surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out what is the problem. [cv::Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) `data` parameter apparently requires **only raw image (pixel array)**.

The buffer we get using `D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileInMemory` is exactly a file wrote by `D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile`, only loaded in memory *(I checked it: after writing the buffer to the file we get the same proper image as created by `D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile`)*

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606565/remove-bmp-header-to-encrypt) that the *bmp header* is 54 bytes at the beginning, so I just added an offset to `imgBuffer` pointer **and the image is now correct.**

```
cv::Mat D3DSurface(ScreenHeight, ScreenWidth, CV_8UC4, (BYTE*)imgBuffer + 54);
```

This works for a *bmp* format, however I don't really know how about other image formats.

.

One thing that bothers me, is the [**cv::imdecode**](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode) method:

> The function reads an image from the specified buffer in the memory.

So maybe it should be used to get `cv::Mat` from a file in memory, the same way `cv::imread` loads file from disk. However I don't how to make it work, as **it uses `InputArray` type as the input**.

.

@Asesh @VuVirt 
Thank you very much for your help.

---

PS. As I mentioned, one more thing to do was to flip the image: (x-axis)

```
cv::Mat D3DSurfaceCorrect;  // new image
cv::flip(D3DSurface, D3DSurfaceCorrect, 0);
```